# How to implement tooltips for ngx-datatable column header

Tags: html, angular, ngx-datatable

Im trying to showup simple tooltips on my ngx-datatable-column header. Important is that I can still use the sort functionality.

Somehow "title" is not working.

```
<ngx-datatable-column title="my Tooltip" [resizeable]="false" [width]="50" name="Name" prop="key" headerClass="text-left">
```

Where I can integrate the title tag?

```html
    <ngx-datatable #table [rows]="rows" [reorderable]="false" columnMode="force" class="bootstrap table-bordered table-hover" [summaryRow]="true" [summaryPosition]="'bottom'" [loadingIndicator]="showLoadingIndicator" headerHeight="auto" rowHeight="auto" footerHeight="auto" summaryHeight="auto">
        <ngx-datatable-column [resizeable]="false" [width]="50" name="Name" prop="key" headerClass="text-left">
            <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <a href="link" target="_blank" class="text-left">
                    {{value}}
                </a>
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548498/ngx-datatable-column-header-tooltip-gets-cut-off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-template` to set header and tooltip for the header:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Part" headerClass="header" [title]="Hello" 
    [summaryFunc]="emptySumm">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template let-column="column">
       <span title="the tooltip">I am a tooltip</span>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

[The complete example can be seen at stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-summary-ghw4kl?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: I noticed that in this Version the sort functionalty not working anymore. Do you have any ideas to fix this with this approach?

Comment: @Izzy030 it looks it is a bag and it [has not resolved](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/431). Also, the title bar [has still not implemented](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1316). So try to use other data tables.

Comment: @@StepUp you seem right thanks for your advise again!

Comment: May I ask what's `ngx-datatable-column`?

Comment: @Jeb50 it is column of [ngx-datatable](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/getting-started)

Comment: I looked [it](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/) but it doesn't have document about it. Do you know where I can learn about that? Thank you.

Comment: @Jeb50 [maybe you can get some info here](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column)